# Reading helper with Zend_View_Helper_* and autoloading

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have set the autoloader to use the Fallback Autoloader like this:

```
$autoloader=Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

If I look at php errors, a notice is generated for every call to a Zend_View_Helper with it trying to read the helper at for example: `/var/www/arc/views/helpers/`. Here is a sample notice:

```
    fopen(/var/www/arc/views/helpers/Layout.php) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]:
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file /private/var/www/arc/ZendFramework-
1.9.5/library/Zend/Loader.php at line: 165
```

It seems like the issue is here:

```
["_prefixToPaths:protected"] => array(1) {
  ["Zend_View_Helper_"] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(17) "Zend/View/Helper/"
    [1] => string(34) "/var/www/arc/views/helpers/"
  }
```

Does using the FallbackAutoloader cause this to happen? It would seem to be a potential performance issue. Also, it should resolve the namespace Zend_View_Helper_ correctly? What am I missing here?

Update:
no, `Zend/View/Helper/Layout.php` is there.

Maybe, I'm missing the point of what the Zend_Loader_Autoloader is supposed to be doing (I think the docs are somewhat weak in this case).

For example, if I adjust my application.ini file to the following:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
includePaths.models= APPLICATION_PATH "/models"
includePaths.helper= APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers/helpers"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

and output the include_path, the models, directory is clearly in the include path but not loading the class.

If I then add the following in a Bootstrap _init function

```
 $autoloader=Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
 $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

It loads fine. For the former situation, do I need to set a Namespace?

**to first comment:**
here are current values with output:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($loader->isFallbackAutoloader(),'is fallback autoloader');
is fallback autoloader bool(false)

Zend_Debug::dump($loader->getDefaultAutoloader(),'default autoloader');
default autoloader array(2) {
  [0] => &string(11) "Zend_Loader"
  [1] => string(9) "loadClass"
}

Zend_Debug::dump($loader->getAutoloaders(),'autoloaders');
autoloaders array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the notice say ?
I would assume that its trying to autoload the helpers from that folder and he doesnt find the classes that he expects.

Comment: right but these are their files and it looks for them in right path (ie Zend/View/Helper) for each helper used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other autoloaders?  If not, you don't need to setFallbackAutoloader( true ).

There's definitely something funky going on.  Did Zend/View/Helper/Layout.php get deleted somehow?

Comment: added info at 'to first comment'